# lein-npm downloads dependencies of dependencies (re-frame template)

Tags: clojure, re-frame

When adding the `lein-npm` plugin to my `re-frame` project to manage `npm` dependencies, `lein-npm` unexpectedly adds dependencies of dependencies. My understanding is that that's unnecessary, because those are either included in my dependency's jar or otherwise not required (because adding `lein-npm` to my project is not required in the first place).

Using the `re-frame` template, I construct this minimal example of my `project.clj`:

```
(defproject stamm "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [re-frame "0.9.1"]]
  :plugins      [[lein-npm "0.6.2"]])
```

Calling `lein npm list` now returns the following:

```
project@0.1.0-SNAPSHOT /path/to/my/project
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY karma@1.0.0
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY karma-chrome-launcher@0.2.0
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY karma-cljs-test@0.1.0
└── UNMET DEPENDENCY karma-junit-reporter@0.3.8
```

This leads to some 15 MByte of dependencies being downloaded, just by adding `lein-npm`. I do not declare any of the `karma*` dependencies shown here in my `project.clj` (in fact: I do not declare any `npm` dependencies at all at this point). They originate from the dependency `[re-frame "0.9.1"]`.

Is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've released re-frame 0.9.2 which puts the NPM dependencies in the `:devDependencies` key. This will mean that they are not transitive, and re-frame consuming projects won't need to install `karma*`.

---

Original answer:

At the time of writing, I don't think there's a way to get around this, but I've opened an issue at https://github.com/RyanMcG/lein-npm/issues/50 to report it.